# How can I parse a URL using a proxy with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, proxy, nokogiri

My app has the following controller action:

```
def test

  #get URL
  url = "http://www.coteur.com/surebet.php"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  @show = doc.at_css("title").text

  @game_data = Array.new
  doc.css('tbody').each do |tr|
    tr.css("tr").each do |f|
      @game_data.push(f.css("td").text)
    end
  end

end
```

And render the following view:

```
<%= @show%>
<div class="bs-example" data-example-id="hoverable-table">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <% if @game_data.empty? %>
        <tr>
          <td>Nope</td>
        </tr>
      <%else%>
        <% @game_data.each do |game|%>
          <tr>
            <td><%= game%></td>
          </tr>
         <%end%>
      <%end%>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Everything work fine locally but on Heroku the `<%= @game_data%>` appears to be empty while it should not be. The problem is that in the US it does not work but in the EU it does. So how can I work this around with a proxy or changing the server location or something else ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your logs when running in the US zone? It is possible that it could be solved without the need for a proxy. Also, as an aside, don't pass user data into `open()`, as it opens up your application to remote code execution.

Comment: You can use `doc.title` instead of `doc.at_css("title").text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork your current Heroku app into the European region with:

```
$ heroku fork --region eu
Creating fork myapp-332... done
Copying slug... done
Copying config vars... done
Fork complete, view it at http://myapp-332.herokuapp.com/
```

Now you'll have a copy of your app running in Europe, which may work better for you.  If that works you can keep the new app and shut down the old one.

See the [fork application docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#fork-application) for more details.

Comment: How do I remove a heroku fork ?

Comment: `heroku apps:destroy -a app-name`